# bbind from a list inside a list after replication in R

Tags: r, list, apply, bind, replication

I'm trying to replicate an experiment in R n=5 times with the `replicate` function. The code is as follows:

```
library(glmnet)
library(coefplot)

code <- replicate(10,{
  data<-matrix(rnorm(100*5,mean=0,sd=1), 100, 5) 
  colnames(data) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
  data <- as.data.frame(data)
  a <- 5 
  b <- 0.8
  c <- 100
  
  data[,2] <- a*data[,1] - b*rnorm(c)
  data[,3] <- a*data[,1] + b*rnorm(c)
  data[,4] <- a*data[,1] - b*rnorm(c)
  
  A <- as.matrix(data)
  set.seed(1)
  results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
    list(
      cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = 1)
    )
  })
  
  lam <- as.data.frame(`names<-`(
    lapply(results, function(x) (x$cvfit$lambda.min)), 
    paste0("X", seq_along(results))
  ))
  
  sigma<- matrix(rnorm(1*5,mean=0,sd=1), 1, 5) 
  colnames(sigma) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
  sub1.sigma <- subset(sigma, select = sigma <= sum(lam))
  sub2.sigma <- subset(sigma, select = sigma <= 2*sum(lam))
  sub3.sigma <- subset(sigma, select = sigma <= 3*sum(lam))
  dplyr::lst(sigma, sub1.sigma, sub2.sigma, sub3.sigma)
  
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

which results in a `list` called `code` in the environment. This list contains 10 list with 4 `double` each (`sigma`,`sub1.sigma`,`sub2.sigma`, and `sub3.sigma`. I want to create 4 dataframes (`sigma, sub1.sigma,...` that each contains the values of each Xi in every run and when no value exist (since i am subseting) to display NA, like the following

```
X1    X2    X3    X4    X5 
0.83  0.83  0.83  0.83  0.83
0.33  0.33  0.33  0.33  NA
0.46  NA    0.46  0.46  0.46
0.22  0.22  NA    0.22  0.22
0.57  0.57  0.57  0.57  0.57
```

I tried to use the following after suggestion

```
result <- lapply(purrr::transpose(code), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

but the error `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :    numbers of columns of arguments do not match` was diplayed. Can someone help me figured it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(code, ~ bind_rows(Filter(function(x) ncol(x) > 0,
         map(.x, as_tibble))))
```

---

If we want to `transpose`

```
transpose(code) %>% 
   map_dfr(~ keep(.x, ~ ncol(.) > 0) %>% 
        map_dfr(as_tibble), .id = 'grp')%>%
     filter(grp %in% 'sigma')
```

Comment: the transpose seems to work better but i have two questions. First how can i keep only the `sigma` values, not the subsets and because the sub1.sigma gives everytime zero it ignores it completely, how can i force it to include with NA?

Comment: @nickolakis Do you need tthe `filter` at the end as in the update

Comment: Thanks, that seems to perfectly work. Do you know why (since i don't use a `set.seed()` the replication produce the same results?

Comment: @nickolakis Can you change the `set.seed` in the code by commenting

Comment: you mean to include it in the code? because i tried the code with and without and it seems that in each run it uses the same data, not different

Comment: I tried by removing `set.seed(1)` and it was giving different `data`.  You could `print(head(A))` in the code

Comment: Why in some casew the `transpose(code)...` is used, i get this error `Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector of length 0`?

Comment: @nickolakis I didn't get that error though.  Is it from a different code

Comment: Is from a larger code that produce the same form of results as the one in the question.

Comment: @nickolakis Can you check the `str(code)` it may be that some `list` elements have all 0 length

Comment: I edited and include the str(code) beacuse i can not see a list (among the first 4 that i use) that have all 0 length.

Comment: @nickolakis in the `str`, there is an element `$ obs                   : Named num [1:10]` which was not in your original question which is a named vector while others are data.frame